# Displaying the image to display in the page that is returned using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How to display the Data that is returned

Here is the data returned :

```
<img src="http://192.168.1.52/MySample/public/assets/uploads/buscompanylogo/2430138c04fd880b9e43aba40cbd5ee3.png" width="80" height="80" alt="photo"><input type="hidden" name="imagetextbox" id="imagetextbox"  value="2430138c04fd880b9e43aba40cbd5ee3.png">
```

I can able to see the `alert(data)` but how can i make the image to appear in the screen ?

Here is my Code

```
<form id="data" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input name="image" type="file" />
    <button>Submit</button>
</form>
<div></div>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$("form#data").submit(function(){    
    var formData = new FormData($(this)[0]);
    $.ajax({
        url: 'companyimageupload',
        type: 'POST',
        data: formData,
        async: false,
        success: function (data) 
        {
              alert(data)
              $("div").data();
              $('#stage_error').html(res).show()
        },
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false
    });    
    return false;
});
</script>
```

How can i do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a div to show result

```
<div id="image"></div>
```

and insert html code received

```
success: function (data) 
{
    //alert(data)
    $('#image').html(data);
},
```

Comment: Thanks, now the alert shall be removed !! Though simple, i just stuck up because of the hidden value that is returned